# How to take out specific values from jQuery.fn.init() and jQuery.fn.init [prevObject: jQuery.fn.init()]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I didnt find a clear way to do it, or a specific way thats why I am asking:

Before anything, this is my html:

```html
<tr class="RateContainer" data-rate="{"id":"AD","meal":{"id":2,"abbreviation":"AD",
...
...
```

I mean; a lot of info inside data-attribute.
then with js I can take this:

```js
var dataRate = $(".RateContainer").map(function () { return $(this).data('rate'); });
```

Which return this object:

`jQuery.fn.init(278) [{…}, {…}, …]`

Where first element is like this:

```
0:
id: "SA"
meal: {id: 1, abbreviation: "", name: "string"}
...
__proto__: Object
```

**Firs Question**:
¿how to take the "ids" out from `jQuery.fn.init(278) [{…}, {…}, …]`, to compare them later?
Where I can see the id(the property I want) using this:

```js
for (var datos in dataRate) {
            console.log(dataRate[datos].id);
        }
```

And give me a list of the id like:

```
SA
 MP
 AD
 MP
...
and go on like 300
```

At this point what I want is this, I have this:

```js
var listaMeals = $("#HotelAvailSideFilterResult_listaMeals2").val();
```

Which print this when I select a Value un a dropdowSelect(Select2):

```
(2) ["AD", "SA"]
0: "AD"
1: "SA"
length: 2
```

So I have an array where I listen when I select 1 item and them keep the selected values.
So what I want to do is where a values is selected like this:

```
(3) ["AD", "SA", "TI"] 
0: "AD" 
1: "SA" 
2: "TI"
```

Make every object hidden that his data value doesn´t contain/includes the ID, somethin like this:

```js
var visible = true;
 if (listaMeals && null != listaMeals && !$.isEmptyObject(listaMeals) && visible) {
                    var existeFiltro = false;

                    $(listaMeals).each(function (i) {
                        if (listaMeals[i].includes(listaMeals_Search)) {
                            existeFiltro = true
                            console.log('encontrado')
                            //- 1 < listaMeals_Search.find(listaMeals[i])
                        }
                        console.log(' no encontrado')
                    });

                    if (!existeFiltro) {
                        visible = false;
                    }
 if (!existeFiltro) {
                        visible = false;
                    }

                if (visible) {
                    $(hotelActual).show();
                } else {
                    $(hotelActual).hide();
                }
```

So **Second question**:
How I can compare the selected values which are already in an array with the id property of a data-attributo which is in a tr inside a lot of thins and wrapper by a div .
Now I´m not taking use of data-attributes I am using this:

```
 $(".product-content.product-wrap.clearfix.product-deatil", divGeneralHoteles).each(function () {
                var hotelActual = $(this);
                var listaMeals_Search = $(this).html().toString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is what you are trying to do :

```
$(".RateContainer").each(function(){ // Each loop will iterate for each element
   var rate = $(this).attr("data-rate")); // This value is in JSON (a string)
   rate = JSON.parse(rate); // This is a JS object.
});
```

If you want to treat all the values at once, you can put each rate into an array.

The jQuery map method is used to format array this way (https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) :

```
$.map(arrayToFormat, formattingFunction);
```

*Addendum* : Your `data-rate` value in HTML is not correctly written.
You should write as follows :

```
data-rate='{"id":"AD","meal":{"id":2,"abbreviation":"AD"}}'
```

Otherwise your string will start & end at each `"`.

Comment: Perfect! Really thank you, Just a last question, Is there a way to take not all the data-info, only the id?? Something like: `var rate = $(this).attr("data-rate".id));` ??

Comment: `var id = rate.id` should work. You can mark it as solved if it is.